# Find elements of similar hierarchy by JavaScript (for web scraping)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

For example, when I select one of the p.item-title elements below, all p.item-title elements should be found (not by the class name). Also, when I select one of the table elements below, all similar tables should be found. I need this for web scraping.

```
<div>
  <div>
    <p class="item-title">...</p>
    <table>...</table>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <p class="item-title">...</p>
    <table>...</table>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery's siblings() method is similar in concept, but it finds similar elements under the same parent node. Is there any method or library to find similar elements from different parent nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jack, I could create a running script.

```
// tags only selector (I need to improve depending on the use case)
function getSelector(element){
  var tagNames = [];
  while (element.parentNode){
      tagNames.unshift(element.tagName);
      element = element.parentNode;
  }
  return tagNames.join(" > ");
}

function getSimilarElements(element) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(element);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do `querySelectorAll` by the path (hierarchy) you want:

```js
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll("div > div > p");
allElements.forEach(p => console.log(p));
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <p class="item-title">Text 1</p>
    <table>...</table>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <p class="item-title">Text 2</p>
    <table>...</table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry. I'd like to find similar elements by NOT using class name. I edited my question to make that clear.

Comment: Edited my answer @rhythm

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery.fn.addEvent = function(type, handler) {
    this.bind(type, {'selector': this.selector}, handler);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.item-title').addEvent('click', function(event) {
        console.log(event.data.selector);
        let elements = document.querySelectorAll(event.data.selector);
                elements.forEach(e => console.log(e));
    });
});
```